# Why does await page.Evaluate() return 'undefined'?

Tags: html, node.js

I'm trying to write a `deploybot` with `nodejs`, but when trying to navigate to the `environments page` it fails to find this button.

Here is the snippet of code:

```
        //wait until element with unique id containing the environments button is there
        await page.waitForSelector('#formatstring_widget_formatstring_14'); 
        
        //check if the element actually exists, so that i can log that.
        const envElement = await page.$('#formatstring_widget_formatstring_14');
        if (envElement != null) {
            console.log('env element exists');
        }  else {
            console.log('no env element found');
        }

        const link = await page.evaluate((env)=> {
            env.innerHTML;
        }, envElement);

       console.log('env= '+link);
```

If I run this, I get a log of:

```
'Env element exists'
'Env = undefined'
```

which means the **element exists**, but there is no **innerHTML?** but when I inspect the source code from the page I'm accessing, the

```
id=#formatstring_widget_formatstring_14 does have inner html
```

**How is this possible?**
**Here is the source code**

```
<div data-mendix-id="51_37_138" class="mx-name-formatString1 mx-link submenu-item page-nav-9" tabindex="0" id="formatstring_widget_formatstring_14" focusindex="0" widgetid="formatstring_widget_formatstring_14" style="">
<div class="formatstring ">
<a href="https://cloud.home.mendix.com/link/deploy/d22310d5-a10f-437b-93d7-c0ceab21d0c6" class="">
Environments</a>
</div></div>
```

Comment: ... shouldn't you be `return`ing something from `page.evaluate()`? `const link = await page.evaluate((env)=> { return env.innerHTML; }, envElement);`

Comment: i tried it, but got the same result. i thought return wasn't necessary when the method is this small and can only return one variable anyway.

Comment: `envElement` is undefined, not `null`

Answer (score -1):

It might be far easier to use the Deploy API from Mendix to automate deployment. See the API here: https://docs.mendix.com/apidocs-mxsdk/apidocs/deploy-api
Regards,
Ronald

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This question is taking the long way and hacking around in the system instead of using a well described API that is made for the use case the person is building. Just my 2 cents.